# Default Behavior of Excel 2019 Opening a Template File

Tags: excel, excel-2019

I have an .xltx document on my desktop that I use to upload conversions to Bing. On my old laptop with earlier versions of Office, double clicking the template file created a new worksheet with the data from the template. On my new laptop with Office 2019 it opens the template file itself to be edited, which I don't want to change. How do I change the behavior so that a double click on the template file opens a new sheet and not the template itself?

Comment: If you right click the template file in Explorer, what are the commands on top of the menu, and which one is bolded?

Comment: If repairing the Office installation does not fix this, see https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2013_release-word/double-click-word-template-does-not-create-new/0ca2b435-18bc-4de0-a51c-2325de0e4c66 for how to change the default verb in the registry.

Comment: Edit is the default in the right menu, and New is under it. It used to be that New was the default.

Comment: Also, the registry keys indicated in that document do not apply as there's no Word.Template.12 folder (or anything similar) under HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT.

Comment: Obviously you need to adjust for the version number because 2019 is 16 (for some reason same as 2013).

Comment: There aren't any folders named Word.xxxxx. It goes from WMVFile to Wordpad to Workspace.

Comment: Then you probably should repair the Office installation. If you go to `\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.dotx`, what's in its `(Default)` value?

Comment: It just shows REG_SZ and (value not set). The same goes for .xltx. How do I repair the Office install?

Answer (score 0):

This was resolved by uninstalling the application and installing it again as suggested by GSerg.